# Clickable image with firestore boolean value

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a recycler-view in android. I have an image in that which is coming from the firestore. With that, I have one more field in firestore, "mOnClick," which is of boolean type. Now I want if the boolean value is true, my image will be clickable else it will be not clickable. Below is my code please help me in doing same.

Model Class:

```
public class Banner extends UserId implements Serializable {
boolean mOnClick;
}

public boolean ismOnClick() {return mOnClick; }
    public void setmOnClick (boolean mOnClick) {this.mOnClick = mOnClick;}
```

Adapter Class:

Here I am not getting what to do... Here .getmOnClick is giving error.

```
public class SliderAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderAdapter.SliderAdapterVH> {

    public List<Banner> bannerList;

    boolean b1=true;
    boolean b2=false;

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SliderAdapterVH viewHolder, final int position) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bannerList.get(position).getmOnClick())) {
            viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setClickable(true);
        } else {
            viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setClickable(false);
        }
```

// I also tried like this but same issue its not working:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bannerList.get(position).toString())) {
                viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setClickable(b1);
            } else {
                viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setClickable(b2);
            }
```

Comment: Here .getmOnClick is giving error. , so what is the error?

Comment: @Zain can you please tell how to do that if mOnClick boolean value is true imageViewBackground .set clickable otherwise it will false.

Comment: Please complete your question

Comment: just do it like `imageViewBackground.setClickable(mOnClick);`

Comment: @Zain I have done something like this now. I have converted my boolean into string then checking... String value =  String.valueOf(bannerList.get(position).ismOnClick());
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+ value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (value =="true") {
            viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setClickable(true);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.imageViewBackground.setClickable(false);
        }   But issue is it's working like if boolean is true click get disable and if boolean is false click getting enabled.